# What kind of capacitor is this? How to read its value code?

Tags: capacitor, identification

I have found some capacitors like this one:
[image: General view]

[image: Dimension]

Does anyone know what kind of capacitor it is? How can I read its value?

Comment: Can I use this [link](http://i337.photobucket.com/albums/n370/jusepics/Tropical_Fish_Color_Chart.png) to decode its value (I have been measuring some with my multimeter and the values some times are too different - maybe they are broken)?

Comment: How much are the values different when you measure them? Many capacitors have a much higher tolerance than resistors, and the values may seem very different than what is rated.

Comment: Is that ruler inch or cm?

Comment: Ucotechnio: try measuring it with your multimeter.

Comment: You're sure it's a capacitor? Back in my childhood I had a bunch of resistors that looked *exactly* like the ones shown in your photos.

Comment: Interesting. However, I have never seen one anywhere like that. Try testing it with a multimeter in resistance mode.

Comment: @jBot-42: I found these capacitors inside an old power regulator. I think it was made in Germany. About the measures, for example, the one that appears in the picture shows a value of 6 nF

Comment: @PlasmaHH: the scale of the ruler is in cm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These images appear to have your answer. This capacitor is a 0.01µF 250v capacitor from old electronic equipment (most likely radio, audio, or television related) containing vacuum tubes. It is similar looking to some of these which are old mica capacitors:
[image]

The stripes on the capacitor can be interpreted using the standard resistor color code to give a 3-digit code like on standard capacitors, where the third digit is the multiplier. In order to read the capacitor code, simply multiply the number created by the first 2 digits by 10<sup>multiplier</sup> to get the final value in pF.

With resistors, the last stripe indicates the tolerance, but with older capacitors it indicates the voltage. If a tolerance is not specified, it is usually 20%.

[image] [image]
[image]

Comment: Unlikely. This is much smaller (7mm high) than the "liquorice allsort" capacitors, which were body dipped, and they are smaller than most vacuum tube era components. I'm curious where these came from - are they East European perhaps? HOWEVER the code may still be useful. I have seen silver-mica caps in a similar case style (but not marking).

Comment: It could be a 0.1 inch ruler.

Comment: I'm inclined to read it as 103 (10nf) 2%.

Comment: Brian Drummond: Usually if there is no tolerance band, it is 20%. Besides, there is no indicated tolerance value for a red band.

Comment: @jBot-42: Thank you for your answer. It is very enlightening. Just one more question, could I replace them with a different type (ceramic or polyester film capacitor for example)?

Comment: Maybe this chart is even better for old components: http://www.sphere.bc.ca/test/color-codes-oldohmandfaradchart.jpg

Comment: @Ucotecnico: If this answer is the most helpful, you should accept it. Yes, you can replace it with a different type, but make sure it fits the rated voltage of 250v. Film or ceramic caps should both work well.

Answer (score 2):

When electronic parts are marked with a color code, it is in floating point.  Each color represents one digit value according to the standard color code.  The first digits are the mantissa, and the last the power of 10 to multiply it by.  For a small capacitor like that, the base unit is almost certainly pico-Farads.

One band will be different somehow.  The number is read ending immediately before that band, which usually specifies a tolerance.  These are less standard and therefore require knowing the manufacturer to know for sure.

You have BRN BLK ORN, so 1 0 3, which means 10 x 10<sup>3</sup>.  We presume pF, so 10,000 pF which means 10 nF in regular engineering notation.  Again, the dotted red band could mean various things, like 20%, or a voltage range, or something.  Without identifying the manufacturer and then finding the appropriate datasheet, you can't be sure.

For this size 10 nF cap, I'd expect maybe around 200 V capability.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please explain what you think is wrong.

Comment: imo this is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not idea about the relation between colour code and floating point. It is very useful.