# Figuring out a substitute for an old amp capacitor - value and type

Tags: amplifier

I'm new to the electronics. 
I have this 60s amp and one leg of the component in the picture broke off. From this post:
[Mullard tropical fish capacitors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219177/mullard-tropical-fish-capacitors)
I realized that it was an old capacitor. From what I've read its 220nF (or 0.22uF). Here is what I want to know:
1 - did I read the coding & values right (is the top red and red - like in = 22?) - is it red, red, yellow, black? And what is the one below black? Is it gold? Like in 100V?
2 - in the answer mentioned above it is said that I should go for a modern capacitor (not look for the old ones). What type of capacitor should I buy? I saw many different ones on aliexpress with 220nF.
3 - would it be a good idea to change all the capacitors I can on this amp?

[image: capacitor]

Comment: 2. Only buy components with datasheets. "Where" in the circuit is it used, i.e. how much voltage rating do you need?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't even understand the question. I was hoping I figure out the values by the color code and then find if it exists in the schematics (to check I was right). Then I would just get in and replace it. I found those values in the schematics (so I think I'm right). But I cannot read the board itself (or the schematics I got for the amp) to tell you what it does, or what the part it is of does, or give you any values that are not in the schematics (and there are no voltage indications there around this part).

Comment: Can you post the schematic?

Comment: If you have the schematic, chanses are good that tje voltage is printed in plain text there.

Comment: Red,red, yellow, black 2 2 0 000 pf +/- 20% resin dipped  polyester (Mullard C280) - see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219177/mullard-tropical-fish-capacitors

Comment: That's the exact link I posted in my question. So I was right! 220nF (or 0.22uF).
As I commented above there is no mentioning of voltage around this capacitor in the schematics. How can I post a schematics here (can't find a way)? 
So what capacitor should I buy to replace it? Should I go for something "special" because its an amp? Should I order from Aliexpress (there are no electronic shops where I live)?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily replace all the capacitors but I'd certainly replace those cracked looking 10nF ones on the right hand side of the picture!

Answer (score 1):

Just want to put it out there:

Here is a entry from a blog of Mullard Magic about TROPICAL FISH CAPACITORS. It contains the original information (with the voltage ratings and the full codes explanation) AND A TABLE OF ALL THE DIFFERENT TROPICAL FISH CAPACITORS MADE with their respective data:
http://www.mullardmagic.co.uk/blog/month/2012-5?pagenumber=2

Here is the datasheet of C280 series capacitors (aka tropical fish):
http://www.electrojumble.org/DATA/C280_Series.pdf